# 'Application not found' when launching JAR file through context menu

Tags: java, jar, path, registry, system-variable

I'm trying to run a .jar file by right-clicking on a folder and selecting an item in the context menu. It works when the `(Default)` value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MyJar\command` is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe" -jar "D:\path\to\MyJar.jar"
```

But with the following value, I get a popup saying "Application not found":

```
java -jar "D:\path\to\MyJar.jar"
```

Either of those lines works just fine if I enter it into the command prompt, so I'm thinking the problem has to do with the registry somehow not "seeing" the <s>classpath</s> path.

Below are my system variable `JAVA_HOME` and the beginning of my system variable `Path`, respectively:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

I'm on windows 8.1, and java version 1.8.0_40.

EDIT: clarified wording. Answer to Guoliang Liu:

1.
Yes.

2.
`java -version` yields:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)  
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode, sharing)
```

3.
`echo %PATH%` begins with

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

`echo %JAVA_HOME%` yields:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you create a key in the registry editor the key is always created as `REG_SZ` value for which environment variables are not resolved. So you would need to create a key as `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. For which the environment variables are resolved. This you can't do in the registry editor.

To achive what you want to do you need

- create the system environment variable JAVA_HOME
- create a registry file `myjar.reg` with the content below

The hex value is `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar "D:\path\to\MyJar.jar"`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MyJar\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,4a,00,41,00,56,00,41,00,5f,00,48,00,4f,00,4d,00,45,00,\
  25,00,5c,00,62,00,69,00,6e,00,5c,00,6a,00,61,00,76,00,61,00,2e,00,65,00,78,\
  00,65,00,22,00,20,00,2d,00,6a,00,61,00,72,00,20,00,22,00,44,00,3a,00,5c,00,\
  70,00,61,00,74,00,68,00,5c,00,74,00,6f,00,5c,00,4d,00,79,00,4a,00,61,00,72,\
  00,2e,00,6a,00,61,00,72,00,22,00,00,00
```

Import the `myjar.reg` into the registry (in the registry editor File -> Import). Then amend the path to your Jar file in the editor.

Comment: It works, but the end result is still pretty much the same as typing out the full path. The goal was to make it work with just `java -jar "D:\path\to\MyJar.jar"`. Are you saying this is not possible?

Comment: Then you need to change the PATH (system environment variable, not the users one) to include the directory where your `java.exe` is stored. If it's not working please describe detailed which steps you have done.

Comment: The only thing I've tried that's not described in the OP is making (Default) of the type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` by following your instructions. And as the OP bears out, the java `bin` folder, which contains `java.exe`, is part of PATH.

Comment: Keep in mind that environment variables are set per user and for the system. If the directory is in the users PATH it will not be found by the system. Simple check: create the `MyJar\command` as `cmd`, so it will open a CMD session with the system environment. Type `set` and check the settings of `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is as in OP, and `PATH` begins with the `bin` folder as in OP (though here with `JAVA_HOME` resolved). It's not identical though; the `PATH` displayed here is of the form "(system PATH);(user PATH)".

Comment: FWIW, I have no trouble creating `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values in the registry editor on Windows 7 and Windows 10. It's a simple matter of right-clicking the key and selecting New > Expandable String Value. There is need to import a hand-crafted `.reg` file.

Comment: @George It's about to create a new key (not a value) with `New > Key` as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and not as `REG_SZ`. To get environment variable references expanded (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/registry-value-types).

Answer (score 0):

it may help to Check following things.

1. after you set the environment variables, have you restarted cmd yet?
2. Is there more than one JDK or JRE? check commond `java -version` to see whethere you have successfully set it up.
3. Also see `echo %PATH%` and `%JAVA_HOME%` to confirm your settings.

hope it helps.

Comment: It sure is a PATH problem. My only wonder is `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` in variable PATH. I don't use oracle so I am not sure whether that will influence or not. Thought it may worth checking it out.

Comment: Is Oracle even a program? I think it's just something that came with the 64 bit JRE installation, because all that's in the folder is three .symlink (shortcut) files to java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe in the `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin` folder. Regardless, I tried removing it from PATH and nothing changed.

Comment: Okay. Now I got nothing to debug this. I would rather try download another jdk. One more thing is that is it possible that PATH is set as user environment variable, but admin does not have it or vice versa. Just guessing.

Comment: Well, there's one window for "User variables for -username-" and one for "System variables", and PATH and JAVA_HOME are both system variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CLASSPATH problem here. The problem is `java.exe` not being found. It is a ***PATH*** problem.